# jquery get elements from object - intl-tel-input get dial code from country data

Tags: jquery, intl-tel-input

I am new to jquery and I'm trying to get the values from the `SelectedCountryData` object in `intl-tel-input` after form submission.

From the documentation `getSelectedCountryData` returns something like below and I want to get the value "93" from it:

```
{
  name: "Afghanistan (‫افغانستان‬‎)",
  iso2: "af",
  dialCode: "93"
}
```

I can successfully return the phone number but `[calling_code] => [object Object]` is returned for the calling code when I use the following:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
     $("#phone-full").val($("#phone").intlTelInput("getNumber")); //this works
     $("#calling_code").val($("#phone").intlTelInput("getSelectedCountryData")); //this doesn't
});
```

Here are the form input fields:

```
<input type="tel" id="phone" value="<?php echo $phone_number ?>">
<input id="phone-full" type="hidden" name="phone_number">
<input id="calling_code" type="hidden" name="calling_code">
```

Comment: We need to see some markup around the input.

Comment: OK - have edited to include the form inputs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to solve this so in the hope that it is useful for someone else:

```
$("#calling_code").val($("#phone").intlTelInput("getSelectedCountryData").dialCode);
```