# How to Seperate country code and phone number seperately in intlTelInput

Tags: javascript, jquery, intl-tel-input

I'm using intlTelInput plugin in my project i want to get country code and phonenumber seperately i tried some solution but no results.
[solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982494/how-to-put-country-dial-code-in-intltelinput-in-brackets) , [Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42699022/jquery-get-elements-from-object-intl-tel-input-get-dial-code-from-country-data)

These are the code that i tried till now

```
    var default_c='in';

  $("#mobilenum").intlTelInput({
    autoFormat: false,
    defaultCountry: default_c,
    utilsScript: "test/lib/libphonenumber/build/utils.js"
  });
```

somehow i got country code using this but this is not the proper way

```
var countrycode = $(".country[class*='active']").attr("data-dial-code");
```

This is what i tried to get phonenumber without country code

```
    var intlNumber =  $("#mobilenum").intlTelInput.getCleanNumber();
```

Comment: `var intlNumber = $("#mobilenum").intlTelInput("getNumber"); `

Comment: I tried this already it returns as [object object] in console

Comment: that object have some data it in. try to check and let us know